# profiling rails application with ruby 1.8.7 and 1.9.2 using ruby-prof

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I am trying to profile my rails applications which is running ruby 1.8.7 and 1.9.2. I have followed the instructions specified [here](https://github.com/rdp/ruby-prof)  but I am getting some strange error which says, "undefined method reverse_merge!". I don't understand why its showing those errors. If I run my app in development mode or production mode its working fine, If I try to run the same in profile mode, I am getting this error.

```
`call': undefined method `reverse_merge!' for #<Proc:0x7fab9b26e500> (NoMethodError)
    from /home/jeevan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p371/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/application.rb:77:in `send'
    from /home/jeevan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p371/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/application.rb:77:in `method_missing'
    from /home/jeevan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p371/gems/rack-1.2.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:73:in `to_app'
    from /home/jeevan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p371/gems/activesupport-3.0.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `inject'
    from /home/jeevan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p371/gems/rack-1.2.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:73:in `each'
    from /home/jeevan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p371/gems/rack-1.2.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:73:in `inject'
    from /home/jeevan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p371/gems/rack-1.2.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:73:in `to_app'
```

Comment: Could you post the full error logs?

Comment: I am also facing the same issue. I added "use Rack::RubyProf, :path => '/temp/profile'" to my config.ru. I am using ruby 1.8.7 and rails 3.0.20